# What is the correct way to logout from IdentityServer4 in React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, expo, identityserver4

I have a small react native expo app that I would like to authenticate for access to APIs using IdentityServer4

I managed to get the sign-in process to work using `AuthSession.useAuthRequest()` where I get the `code` and I exchange it for `access token` and `refresh token` with `AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync()`, that I can use to call the APIs.

The problem is when I want to logout.

I call the `AuthSession.revokeAsync()` and get the success, but when the user tries to login again they are not prompted for a password again, but are immediately logged in and issued a new access token.

This is a problem for when the user wants to switch the account they are using.

what is the correct way to perform the logout so that the user will be asked to input their credentials again next time they try to login

Here is my code for login/logout

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import * as AuthSession from 'expo-auth-session';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

export default function App() {
  WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
  const discovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery(
    'https://localhost:5000'
  );

  const redirectUrl = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
    native: 'exp://127.0.0.1:19000',
    preferLocalhost: true,
  });

  const clientId = 'cee58f8c-8187-4cfd-9964-1948cd621939'

  const scopes = ['openid', 'profile', 'IdentityServerApi', 'api-v1', 'offline_access'];

  const config = {
    clientId: clientId,
    redirectUri: redirectUrl,
    scopes: scopes,
    grantType: 'authorization_code',
    extraParams: { code_verifier: request?.codeVerifier },
  };

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
    config,
    discovery
  );

  const handleLogin = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      promptAsync({ useProxy: false });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error: ', e);
    }
  }, [promptAsync]);

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState()
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response && response.type === 'success') {
      const getCodeAsync = async () => {
        const codeResp = await AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync(
          {
            code: response.params.code,
            clientId: clientId,
            redirectUri: redirectUrl,
            grantType: 'authorization_code',
            scopes: scopes,
            extraParams: { code_verifier: request?.codeVerifier },
          },
          discovery
        );
        console.log('codeResp: ', codeResp);

        setAccessToken(codeResp?.accessToken)
        setRefreshToken(codeResp?.refreshToken)

      };

      getCodeAsync();
    }
  }, [response]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserInfoAsync = async () => {
      const userInfo = await AuthSession.fetchUserInfoAsync(
        {
          accessToken
        }
        , discovery
      );

      console.log('userInfo: ', userInfo);
      const availableActors = JSON.parse(userInfo?.actors)
      console.log("availableActors", availableActors)
    };

    getUserInfoAsync()
  }, [accessToken]);

  const handleLogout = async (aToken, rToken) => {
    try {
      const revokeRespAccessToken = await AuthSession.revokeAsync(
        {
          token: aToken,
          tokenTypeHint: 'access_token',
          clientId: clientId
        },
        discovery
      );

      const revokeRespRefreshToken = await AuthSession.revokeAsync(
        {
          token: rToken,
          tokenTypeHint: 'refresh_token',
          clientId: clientId
        },
        discovery
      );

      if (revokeRespAccessToken) {
        setAccessToken(null)
      }

      if (revokeRespRefreshToken) {
        setRefreshToken(null)
      }

    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error: ', e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <Button type='submit' onPress={() => handleLogin()} title='Login'>
        <Text>Login</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button type='submit' onPress={() => handleLogout(accessToken, refreshToken)} title='Logout'>
        <Text>Logout</Text>
      </Button>
      <StatusBar style='auto' />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: I've been stuck on the exact same issue here & couldn't find any solutions so far, did you figure out how to solve it in the end?

Comment: No, still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an alternative way, something like this

```
const authDiscoveryDocument = {
  authorizationEndpoint: `${domain}/authorize`,
  tokenEndpoint: `${domain}/oauth/token`,
}

const authRequestConfig = {
  redirectUri,
  clientId,
  scopes: [...],

  // This option is the key: Prompt is from expo-auth-session
  // this will make web login prompt ALWAYS ask username/password when you call promptAsync
  // even if user is still logged in
  // Otherwise the browser will ALWAYS use existing credentials to silently login
  // hence not allowing users to switch account
  prompt: Prompt.Login,
}

const [authRequest] = useState(new AuthRequest(authRequestConfig))
const [authResponse, setAuthResponse] = useState(null)

const handleLogin = async () => {
  const loginResponse = await authRequest.promptAsync(authDiscoveryDocument, {
    // @showInRecents option allows web login screen to stay "in memory" even if user
    // switches to a diff app in the middle of authentication (e.g. checking an authenticator for code)
    showInRecents: true,
  })
  setAuthResponse(loginResponse)
}

const handleLogout = async () => {
  ...
  // logout will simply remove the access token from AsyncStorage OR SecureStorage
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem('tokens')
  // go back to load login screen
}

useEffect(() => {
  const saveAccessTokens = async () => {
    const tokens = await exchangeCodeAsync(...)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('tokens', JSON.stringify(tokens))
  }

  if (authResponse && authResponse.type === 'success') {
    saveAccessTokens()
  }
}, [...])



return (
  ...
  <Button title="Login" onPress={handleLogin} disabled={!authRequest} />
)
```